# Derivative of distortion/objective function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, machine-learning

Please help me understand how do you obtain

$$J' = 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}r_{nk}(x_{n} - \mu_{k})$$

from

$$J = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{K}r_{nk}\left \| x_{n} - \mu _{k} \right \|^{2}$$

Given

- N data points $x^n \space(n=1,...,N)$
- K clusters
- $r_{nk}$: 1-of-K coding scheme
- $\mu_{k}$: Cluster centres

when deriving J that is the distortion function that should be optimized by finding $\mu_{j}$ and $r_{nk}$ such that J is a minimum. Also, how do you solve $J'$ for $\mu_{j}$?. The result is

$$\mu_{k} = \frac{\sum_{n} r_{nk}x_{n}}{\sum_{n} r_{nk}}$$

but I want to understand the procedure to obtain it

Comment: Is $\left \| x_{n} - \mu _{k} \right \|^{2}$ not the same as $\left( x_{n} - \mu _{k} \right)^{2}$? And do you mean $m_k$ instead of $m_j$?

Comment: Well, in $J'$ we are trying to optimize $\mu_{k}$ with the $r_{nk}$ held fixed.  $J'$ is the result of deriving $J$ that is basically the sum of the squares of the distances of each data point to its assigned vector $\mu_{k}$, so that's the two-norm vector or euclidean distance. I don't think they are the same. The second is a typo. Thanks!